# Query JET 4 database with SSIS

Tags: ms-access, windows-server-2012-r2, ssis-2012, jet

I want to use SSIS 2012 (2014?) to extract data from an old Access 2000 database once a month. The file is copied from a plant such that we have exclusive access to the file. We only want to read the data.

On the development machine it works fine, since a JET 4 Driver is installed. On the 2012 Server machine, it doesn't.

I've searched the net. There is no 64Bit Jet 4 driver. The newer driver for access 2010 (Version 12?) is installed on the machine, but it throws an exception that it can't open the older format.

Any ideas how I could extract the data regularly? Updating to a new Access format is sadly no option (unless there would be powershell script which would allow me to update my copy of the database monthly).

Comment: Which version of Access? The 64 bit driver works quite well with Access 2000. Have you considered CSVs?

Comment: I would be happy with CSV. How to create CSV out of the .mdb without ODBC driver? I just get a copy of the .mdb.

Comment: You did not say which version of Access. This may help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2010/01/21/how-to-get-a-x64-version-of-jet/

Comment: I am not sure which version it is. It is .mdb. It could be Access 2000 or access 97. I just have the file. I've read about the ACE drivers and tried them but when accessing the .mdb with SSIS I get the version error.

Comment: Have you tried VBScript?

Comment: VBScript in which environment? We don't have Access installed on the SSIS-server machine. I only have the .mdb file. All other solutions like Powershell or C# would also depend on a working OLE DB driver. I am pretty much stuck here....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261478/how-to-programmatically-convert-access-1997-mdb-to-access-2007-accdb